# Resizing a parition on a virtual disk in Window Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtual-machines, partition

The virtual disk in question is `400 GB`, with an `80 GB` `C` partition and a `320 GB` `D` partition.

If the virtual disk is resized to `500 GB`, is it possible to extend the `C` partition into the new space?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  No third party software required.  I am assuming by **virtual disk** you mean that this is a virtual machine, and I'm also assuming you are talking about VMware, not Hyper-V.  If my assumptions are correct, then...:

1. Shut down the server that you need to extend the C: drive on
2. Take a backup of VM, or as a minimum, secure a copy of the VMDKs
3. Extend the underlying VMDK
4. Using a gash Win2k3 server, mount the VMDK containing the to-be-expanded C: drive
5. Use DISKPART to extend the volume (see [MS KB325590](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325590))
6. Shutdown the gash VM, un-mount the VMDK
7. Start up original VM and voila, bigger C: drive

Comment: "gash Win2k3 server"?  Where I come from, we don't speak like that in front of ladies or children, whatever we think of the OS.

Comment: Very good!! ;-)

Comment: But seriously, I don't understand what you mean by the term.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but you will need to use 3rd party software [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) normally does the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a 3rd party tool since even though you have enlarged the `VMDK`, the unallocated space is still at the end of the disk, which is not adjacent to `C`.  I think you could use Partition Assistant, and [this article](http://www.partition-magic.org/windows-server-2003/resize-partition-windows-server-2003.html) could help.

Comment: Fair point - what ever happened to one VMDK, one partition?